# Moodle MoodleSession 1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z

Tags: moodle

Moodle выдает странные куки. В чем может быть проблема? На сервере с временем все ок. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё в порядке. Это дата и время в формате [ISO 8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (`гггг-мм-ддTчч:мм:сс.мксZ`).

Этот формат повсеместно используется для машиночитаемого представления времени, потому что он:

- содержит компоненты в порядке убывания значимости. Это позволяет легко сравнивать и сортировать значения без необходимости заглядывания вперёд,
- позволяет задавать время и временны́е интервалы с различной точностью,
- не содержит лишних символов (таких как пробелы).